# Java Send Vector of objects from server to client

Tags: java, server

On my serverside I have a function to create a vector containing all a users friends. I then want to send this array of objects to the client so they can see them.

```
public void LoadFriendsList(User username) throws SQLException, IOException 
    {
        Vector<User> updateFriends = new Vector<>();
        Vector<String> Friends = new Vector<>();
        User nextUser;

        Friends = username.getFriends();

        for (int i = 0; i < username.getFriends().size(); i++)
        {
            nextUser = newUser(Friends.get(i));
            updateFriends.add(nextUser);
        }
        outToClient.writeObject(updateFriends);
}
```

This is the code for the server and as far as I can tell works fine.

```
public void LoadFriendsList() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException 
{

    ObjectInputStream inFromServer;
    inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    Vector<User> Friends = (Vector<User>)inFromServer.readObject();
}
```

The client however just hangs on the 2nd line and won't do anything

Comment: How do you create the ObjectOutputStream? You may need to `flush` it

Comment: consider using JSON to represent the objects when transmitting them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call flush on the stream after writing to it.